# Sharepoint 2007 sequential workflow in VS 2008

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, wss-3.0

I installed Visual Studio 2008. I try to create Sharepoint 2007 sequential workflow. As soon as I hit: New project ->  sharepoint 2007 sequential workflow
I get the error: could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SharePoint, Version 12.0.0.0, culture=neutral Public token=... or one of its dependencies. File not found.

I have installed WSS 3.0 on a server and Visual Studio on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the dll files from the sharepoint server in the directory

*C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web server extensions\12\ISAPI*

to a directory on the local computer, *C: \ Windows \ assembly \ GAC.*